# How do I show the sidebar and header on a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, sidebar, header

I just tried the base example Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page>
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page
 <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

and there is no header or sidebar on the preview, just the content. I thought that the header & sidebar were automatically set to be visible - what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two should show by default, though the sidebar might be hidden for your user.

Add the following to the page declaration to explicitly show them.

`<apex:page sidebar="true" showHeader="true">`

You can get all the info on the `apex:page` tag [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm)

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian - per my comment above, adding `sidebar="true"` and `showHeader="true"` have no effect. Is there a user setting that would override these values (seems odd if you explicitly set them that they would still be overridden)

Comment: Are you displaying this page in Lightning, by any chance?

Comment: I believe so - I just signed up for a Developer account, and the url includes `lightning.force.com`

Comment: Header/Sidebars will NEVER show in Lightning (like you see in the post that @Oleksiy made). Switch to Classic and they should work

Comment: Marking as correct - I guess that solves the problem, but as you're developing lightning pages, wouldn't you want the header and sidebar? How do you include those elements if you want them on a visualforce page in Lightning?

Comment: Lightning comes with its own header/sidebar. I am not sure how you're navigating to the page, but the expected UX is to use a VF Component (a VF Lightning Component) and place it on a standard page, or create your own App and FlexiPages and put it there. I don't know enough about your environment to recommend a path... and, honestly, this is not really the place to have that conversation either.

Comment: Ah... that makes more sense - the documentation seems like you are creating a full page rather than a page element. I literally clicked to create a new VF page, then clicked the preview button, and only saw the page content. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

**In Salesforce classic** the `showHeader="true"` and `sidebar="true"` attributes on the `<apex:page>` element enable both the header and sidebar.

**In Salesforce lightning** these values are automatically overridden. You can still enable them by using the `setup="true"` attribute on the `<apex:page>` element this enables both the header and sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

[Visualforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm) says:

> **showHeader** Boolean value that specifies whether the Salesforce tab header is included in the page. If true, the tab header is displayed.
> If not specified, this value defaults to true.
>
> ***Note: In Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 the value of this attribute is overridden, and is always false.***

Comment: Thanks @Olesky, but adding `showHeader="true"` and `sidebar="true"` yield the same result (no header or sidebar).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by adding the setUp = "true" attribute to the  tag